# Scope of class variable

Tags: ruby, class-variables

Setting a class variable `@@foo` in two classes `B` and `C`, where neither is a subclass of the other but they both include a common module `A`, seems to create `@@foo` separately for `B` and `C`, which `A` cannot access:

```
module A; end
class B; include A; @@foo = 1 end
class C; include A; @@foo = 2 end

module A; p @@foo end # => NameError: uninitialized class variable @@foo in A
class B; p @@foo end  # => 1
class C; p @@foo end  # => 2
```

But when `@@foo` is assigned in `A`, which works as an ancestor to both `B` and `C`, the `@@foo` that `B` and `C` access becomes the `@@foo` of `A`.

```
module A; @@foo = 3 end
class B; p @@foo end  # => 3
class C; p @@foo end  # => 3
```

What happened to the `@@foo` of `B` and `C`? Are they deleted when any of its ancestor's `@@foo` is assigned?

Comment: @ArupRakshit That is not the answer. Actually, my question came out of that answer. Your answer is the starting point of this question.

Comment: I got that.. Let me think.. :-) Good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code appears in both `rb_cvar_set` and `rb_cvar_get` in MRI's `variable.c`:

```
if (front && target != front) {
    st_data_t did = id;

    if (RTEST(ruby_verbose)) {
        rb_warning("class variable %"PRIsVALUE" of %"PRIsVALUE" is overtaken by %"PRIsVALUE"",
          QUOTE_ID(id), rb_class_name(original_module(front)),
          rb_class_name(original_module(target)));
    }
    if (BUILTIN_TYPE(front) == T_CLASS) {
        st_delete(RCLASS_IV_TBL(front),&did,0);
    }
}
```

`id` is the C-internal representation of the variable name (`@@foo`).

`front` is the class in which the variable is *currently being accessed* (`B`/`C`).

`target` is the *most distant ancestor* in which the variable has also *ever been defined* (`A`).

**If `front` and `target` are not the same**, Ruby warns that `class variable #{id} of #{front} is overtaken by #{target}`.

The **variable name is then literally deleted** from `front`'s RCLASS_IV_TBL, so that on subsequent lookups, the search for that variable name *"falls through"* or *"bubbles up"* to the most distant ancestor in which the variable is defined.

---

Note that this check and deletion happen **not just on cvar gets, but on sets as well:**

```
$VERBOSE = true

module A; end
class B; include A; @@foo = 1; end # => 1

module A; @@foo = 3 end # => 3
class B; p @@foo = 1 end # => 1
#=> warning: class variable @@foo of B is overtaken by A


module A; p @@foo end # => 1
```

In this example, even though **it's** `A`**'s value of** `3` **being overwritten** by the value `1` being set in `B`, we **still receive the same warning** that it's `B`'s class variable being overtaken by `A`!

While it is usually more surprising to the average Ruby coder to find that the value of their variable is changing in various, perhaps unexpected, places (i.e. in "parent"/"grandparent"/"uncle"/"cousin"/"sister" modules and classes), the trigger and the wording both indicate that **the warning is actually intended to inform the coder that the variable's *"source of truth"* has changed.**

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. The result `1` for `A` in your last line was surprising to me. The existence of the line with assiging `3` in `A` makes difference to that last line. So, to rephrase it, it seems that (1) Setting and getting can be passed through the ancestor hierarchy upwards or downwards, but (2) that is only within the domain where the variable exists, and (3) the existence can be only inherited downwards, and (4) non-top most variables in the hierarchy are deleted.

Answer (score 1):

My notes below are taken from [Metaprogramming Ruby (by Paolo Perrotta)](http://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby), which I happened to be reading right now just as I came across your question.  I hope that these excerpts (page numbers will be in parentheses) and my explanation are helpful to you.

Keep in mind that *class variables* are different from *class instance variables*.

> A Class instance variable belongs to an object of class `Class`, and is
>   accessible only by the class itself - not by an instance or by a
>   subclass. (106)

The *class variable*, on the other hand, belongs to class *hierarchies*.  That means that it belongs to any class as well as all descendants of that class.

Here is an example from the author:

```
@@v = 1

class MyClass
  @@v = 2
end

@@v    # => 2
```

> You get this result because class variables don't really belong to
>   classes - they belong to class *hierarchies*.  Since @@v is defined in
>   the context of `main`, it belongs to `main's` class `Object`... and to
>   all the descendants of `Object`.  `MyClass` inherits from `Object`, so
>   it ends up sharing the same class variable. (107)

But also, since your specific question has to do not only with classes but also with modules:

> When you include a module in a class, Ruby will create an anonymous
>   class that wraps the module and inserts the anonymous class in the
>   chain, just above the including class itself. (26)

So, as you look at `B.ancestors`, you will see:

```
=> [B, A, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Similarly, for `C.ancestors`, you will see:

```
=> [C, A, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

If we keep in mind that class variables belong to class hierarchies, then the class variable `@@foo`, as soon as it is defined in `Module A` (and so, the anonymous class just above `B` that is created as soon as `B` includes `A`), will belong to `B` (and also to `C`, since it includes `A`).

To put it simply:

1. When `@@foo` was only defined in `B` and in `C` (but not in `A`), then `B` had a class variable `@@foo` that was different than the class variable `@@foo` in `C`.  This is because the class variables are only accessible to that class and to all descendants.  But `B` and `C` are related through their ancestor `A`, and not through their descendants.
2. As soon as `@@foo` was defined in `A`, that class variable became inherited by all descendants of `A` - that is, `B` and `C`.  From here on out, the reference to `@@foo` in class `B` is really referencing the class variable that belongs to `A`.  The original `@@foo` which was defined in `B` has been <s>overwritten</s> replaced (taken over by its ancestor).  The same has happened to the `@@foo` in `C`.  `B` and `C` can both write to and read from the same class variable `@@foo`, since it belongs to their common ancestor, `A`.

At this point, anyone of `A`, `B`, or `C` can all modify `@@foo`.  For example:

```
class B
  p @@foo  # => 3
  @@foo = 1
end

module A
  p @@foo  # => 1
end
```

Comment: In think the answer part of what you wrote is: `The original @@foo which was defined in B has been overwritten (taken over by its ancestor).`. I don't think the expression "overwrite" is accurate. It implies that there is still such variable.

Comment: That is true.  *Overwrite* may not be the best word.  Perhaps *replaced* is a better word - replaced by a completely different variable that belongs to a different (ancestor) class, but with the same name.