# Ruby class object extension

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm new to Ruby and I have been trying to learn metaprogramming. I want to define a class and count the number of objects created then print it out when `ClassName.Count` is called. (This will give the number of objects that have been created).
This is what I have so far:

```
class Test
  @@number = 0

  def initialize
    @@number += 1
  end

  def self.Count
    puts "number is #{@@number}"
  end 
end 

Test.Count() # => 0

test1 = Test.new
test2 = Test.new
Test.Count() # => 2

test3 = Test.new
Test.Count() # => 3
```

This works and prints the right number of objects created. However, I am supposed to do this using class object extension, that is without using self methods (`self.foo`) or class attributes (`@@number`). This is where I got stuck. I'm not sure what the difference is between my solution and the one I need to implement. Also any suggestions for readings about this topic would be more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this meet your requirements?

```
class Test
  @count = 0
  def initialize
    Test.instance_variable_set(:@count, Test.instance_variable_get(:@count)+1)
  end
  def count
    Test.instance_variable_get(:@count)
  end
end

Test.instance_variable_get(:@count)
  #=> 0
test1 = Test.new
test1.count
  #=> 1
test2 = Test.new
test2.count
  #=> 2
test1.count
  #=> 2
Test.instance_variable_get(:@count)
  #=> 2
```

Comment: I want to be able to call count from Test class (`Test.count` ) and not from the objects created from it (i.e test1, test2 etc..). Why does the compiler consider count undefined for the Test class here? Is this where I'd need a singleton method (self)?

Comment: Ruby would complain that there is no class method `count()`, not that there is no class instance variable `@count`. To have `Test.count` return the value of `@count` you need to create a class method `count()` either directly (`def self.count...`) or, equivalently, with `attr_reader` or `attr_accessor`, as @Jesse suggested.  But don't these (as well as having a class instance variable) violate your prohibitions? Are you certain that you are interpreting "using class object extension" correctly?

Answer (score 1):

It's true that you really should never use "class variables" (e.g. `@@foo`); they aren't what most people think they are, and they behave in surprising / stupid ways. In most cases when you think you need a "class variable", really all you need is an instance variable on the class itself (which, as an object, is an instance itself, of the class `Class`).

I don't know why you aren't allowed to define singleton methods (i.e. "self methods"), but here is another way of doing it using the `class << self` syntax.

```
class Test
  @count = 0

  class << self
    attr_accessor :count
  end

  def initialize
    self.class.count += 1
  end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by surprising or stupid ways? I understand that an instance variable of the class can be used here, but are there cases where class variables are necessary / more useful in this context?

Comment: @akallel This question has a great example of a surprising class variable behavior: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21907938/scope-of-class-variable . They exhibit unexpected inheritance behaviors and related classes overwrite variables when you don't expect that. There really is no good use case for class variables in Ruby that can't be solved better another way.